# trying to get info from a database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Im trying to get info from a database and write it into text views to display the info from the database after i input the order name

```
package com.example.mauricio.pairlines;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Seeorder extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seeorder);
        final EditText etOrdernum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrdernum);
        final TextView tvPilotname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPilotname);
        final TextView tvPilotcash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPilotcash);
        final TextView tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        final TextView tvPlanemodel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlanemodel);
        final TextView tvHoobsstart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHoobsstart);
        final TextView tvHoobsend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHoobsend);
        final TextView tvWatchtime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWatchtime);
        final TextView tvHoobstime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHoobstime);
        final TextView tvGas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGas);
        final TextView tvLiter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etLiter);
        final TextView tvRepairname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRepairname);
        final TextView tvRepaircost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRepaircost);
        final TextView tvTravelexpense = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTravelexpense);
        final TextView tvOthername1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOthername1);
        final TextView tvOthercost1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOthercost1);
        final Button bTickets = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTickets);
        final Button bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        final Button btSerach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSerach);

        btSerach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final String ordernum = etOrdernum.getText().toString();


                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            int succees = jsonResponse.getInt("success");

                            if(succees==1){
                                JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("myorder");
                                JSONObject jsonName1 = array.getJSONObject(0);
                                String ordernum= jsonName1.getString("ordernum")+" Numero de orden";
                                JSONObject jsonName2 = array.getJSONObject(1);
                                String pilotname= jsonName2.getString("pilotname")+" Nombre del piloto";
                                JSONObject jsonName3 = array.getJSONObject(2);
                                String pilotcash= jsonName3.getString("pilotcash")+"$ Sueldo del piloto";
                                JSONObject jsonName4 = array.getJSONObject(3);
                                String date= jsonName4.getString("date")+" Fecha ";
                                JSONObject jsonName5 = array.getJSONObject(4);
                                String planemodel= jsonName5.getString("planemodel")+" Modelo del avion";
                                JSONObject jsonName6 = array.getJSONObject(5);
                                String hoobsstart= jsonName6.getString("hoobsstart")+" Hoobs inicio";
                                JSONObject jsonName7 = array.getJSONObject(6);
                                String hoobsend= jsonName7.getString("hoobsend")+"Hoobs final";
                                JSONObject jsonName8 = array.getJSONObject(7);
                                String watchtime= jsonName8.getString("watchtime")+" Watch time";
                                JSONObject jsonName9 = array.getJSONObject(8);
                                String hoobstime= jsonName9.getString("hoobstime")+" Hoobstime";
                                JSONObject jsonName10 = array.getJSONObject(9);
                                String gas= jsonName10.getString("gas")+" Combustible";
                                JSONObject jsonName11 = array.getJSONObject(10);
                                String liter= jsonName11.getString("liter")+" litros de combustible";
                                JSONObject jsonName12 = array.getJSONObject(11);
                                String repairname= jsonName12.getString("repairname")+" Nombre de refaccion";
                                JSONObject jsonName13 = array.getJSONObject(12);
                                String repaircost= jsonName13.getString("repaircost")+"$ Costo de refaccion";
                                JSONObject jsonName14 = array.getJSONObject(13);
                                String travelexpense= jsonName14.getString("travelexpense")+"$ Costo viaticos";
                                JSONObject jsonName15 = array.getJSONObject(13);
                                String othername1= jsonName15.getString("othername1")+"$ Otros Concepto";
                                JSONObject jsonName16 = array.getJSONObject(13);
                                String othercost1= jsonName16.getString("othercost1")+"$ Otros precio";





                                tvPilotname.setText(pilotname);
                                tvPilotcash.setText(pilotcash);
                                tvDate.setText(date);
                                tvPlanemodel.setText(planemodel);
                                tvHoobsstart.setText(hoobsstart);
                                tvHoobsend.setText(hoobsend);
                                tvWatchtime.setText(watchtime);
                                tvHoobstime.setText(hoobstime);
                                tvGas.setText(gas);
                                tvLiter.setText(liter);
                                tvRepairname.setText(repairname);
                                tvRepaircost.setText(repaircost);
                                tvTravelexpense.setText(travelexpense);
                                tvOthername1.setText(othername1);
                                tvOthercost1.setText(othercost1);





                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Seeorder.this);
                                builder.setMessage("La orden no existe")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                };

                SeeorderRequest seeorderRequest = new SeeorderRequest(ordernum, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Seeorder.this);
                queue.add(seeorderRequest);
                bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent registerIntent =new Intent(Seeorder.this, UserArea.class);
                        Seeorder.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is the logcat

```
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:293)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:521)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.Seeorder$1$1.onResponse(Seeorder.java:70)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.Seeorder$1$1.onResponse(Seeorder.java:59)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-25 14:36:55.833 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-25 14:36:55.834 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-25 14:36:55.834 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
08-25 14:36:55.834 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
08-25 14:37:04.248 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = false
08-25 14:37:07.594 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2c32922a time:3689475
08-25 14:37:09.092 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.mauricio.pairlines time:3690974
08-25 14:37:09.203 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = false
08-25 14:37:09.392 4782-4821/com.example.mauricio.pairlines D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb75eb718 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb765d220
08-25 14:37:09.398 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2e649e84 time:3691280
08-25 14:37:10.182 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = false
08-25 14:37:10.452 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = false
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:293)
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:521)
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.Seeorder$1$1.onResponse(Seeorder.java:70)
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.example.mauricio.pairlines.Seeorder$1$1.onResponse(Seeorder.java:59)
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
08-25 14:37:19.005 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
08-25 14:37:19.006 4782-4782/com.example.mauricio.pairlines W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

and this is the response i get from the db if i use postman to send ordernum

```
{"success":1,"myorder":[{"ordernum":"1","pilotname":"1","pilotcash":"2","date":"3","planemodel":"4","hoobsstart":"5","hoobsend":"6","watchtime":"7","hoobstime":"8","gas":"9","liter":null,"repairname":"11","repaircost":"12","travelexpense":null,"othername1":"14","othercost1":"15"}]}
```

problem is i cant even find the problem on logcat it seems its this 
JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1) and i think that means theres nothing on myorder array in slot 1 but it should be a "pilotname":"1"

Comment: Can you post the content of `JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("myorder");`

Comment: Have you tried to parse the response to an object?

Comment: @Hackerman the array my order is this [{"ordernum":"1","pilotname":"1","pilotcash":"2","date":"3","planemodel":"4","hoobsstart":"5","hoobsend":"6","watchtime":"7","hoobstime":"8","gas":"9","liter":null,"repairname":"11","repaircost":"12","travelexpense":null,"othername1":"14","othercost1":"15"}]}

Comment: @pamobo0609 parse the response to an object?

Comment: Yeah, I mean, using `Gson` or something like that.. What you do is that you do a class that matches the JSON, with the success attribute as String and the myorder attribute as an arraylist, and using `Gson`, you can transform the JSON to an instance of that object

Comment: @pamobo0609 isnt this tline doing that? JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("myorder");

Comment: Yes, in a certain way. By doing things with `Gson` you can save time and code, by parsing directly the JSON to an object, which will give you access to the attributes with get methods. This way, you can check for a NPE error faster or well in this case, the out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a little bit of refactoring on your `if` statement, because the array just have one item:

```
if(succees==1){
   JSONArray array = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("myorder");
   JSONObject orderObj = array.getJSONObject(0);

   String ordernum= orderObj.getString("ordernum")+" Numero de orden";
   String pilotname= orderObj.getString("pilotname")+" Nombre del piloto";
   String pilotcash= orderObj.getString("pilotcash")+"$ Sueldo del piloto";
   String date= orderObj.getString("date")+" Fecha ";
   String planemodel= orderObj.getString("planemodel")+" Modelo del avion";
   String hoobsstart= orderObj.getString("hoobsstart")+" Hoobs inicio";
   String hoobsend= orderObj.getString("hoobsend")+"Hoobs final";
   String watchtime= orderObj.getString("watchtime")+" Watch time";
   String hoobstime= orderObj.getString("hoobstime")+" Hoobstime";
   String gas= orderObj.getString("gas")+" Combustible";
   String liter= orderObj.getString("liter")+" litros de combustible";
   String repairname= orderObj.getString("repairname")+" Nombre de refaccion";
   String repaircost= orderObj.getString("repaircost")+"$ Costo de refaccion";
   String travelexpense= orderObj.getString("travelexpense")+"$ Costo viaticos";
   String othername1= orderObj.getString("othername1")+"$ Otros Concepto";
   String othercost1= orderObj.getString("othercost1")+"$ Otros precio";
```

> Take a look at this article too: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/

Comment: this fixed that problem only problem now is that it crashes after i click buscar

Comment: @Aimatos, I understand but that is another issue...You can open another question, put the link to the question here as a comment and I will help you to resolve it, no problem!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, ill try fixing it mysel first =) and if i cant ill sure post here, Its hard to be self taught programer but i try to solve what i can

Comment: No problem @Aimatos...Saludos!